# ChildBrowser Plugin of PhoneGap displaying an error

Tags: android, cordova, android-widget

Recently i built an android app in PhoneGap , and now i want a twitter sharing feature so i am planning to add a childbrowser where i will give the url of twitter sharing. Now i have done all the steps given in [ChildBrowser Github](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/Android/ChildBrowser) and also i have used ondevice ready function, but my code is displaying an error in the emulator as soon as i hit the tweet button ie.        "  TypeError: window.plugins.childBrowser is undefined  "       . Now um almost trying on this code for more than 7 hours and unable to solve it . can anyone tell where i am wrong ?
i am pasting the code below

```
<title> Javascript Code</title>
```

```
    var childBrowser; 

    function onBodyLoad() 
    { 
    document.addEventListener("deviceready",onDeviceReady,false); 
    } 

    function onDeviceReady() 
    { 
        phoneGapReady.innerHTML = "PhoneGap is Ready"; 
        childBrowser = ChildBrowser.install(); 
    }

    function openChildBrowser(url) 
    { 

        try 
        { 
             //alert("check");
            //both of these should work... 
            window.plugins.childBrowser.showWebPage(url); 
            childBrowser.showWebPage(url); 
        } 
        catch (err) 
        { 
            alert(err); 
        } 
    } !-- end of Javascript function  <body onload="onBodyLoad()">   <a onclick="openChildBrowser('http://www.google.com')">  <img style="float:left" src="tweet.jpg" style="margin-left:10px" width="100" height="40"> </a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Its possibly a scope issue....

http://www.mredkj.com/tutorials/reference_js_intro_ex.html

also try

```
var childBrowser = '';
```

or

```
var childBrowser = null;
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you included childbrowser.java childbrowser.js and phonegap.js files?